# Why won't this .NET project compile?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nuget

I'm building a project as part of a course, I didn't build it from scratch but I've got it at a stable level that compiles perfectly with no errors or warnings.

I need to add Entity Framework Core. The video shows the instructor installing 2.1.4 even though the latest is 3.1.4. What the heck, I install the older version. Everything's still peachy.

But I don't want 2.1.4, I want 3.1.4. I won't go into the reasons, but suffice to say that version supports EDMX. Please don't question me on that. Incidentally I have 3 projects in the solution and only one of them had the EF Core installed. Does that matter? Anyway, after installing 3.1.4 in that one project I get this.

```
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4 directly to project OdeToFood to resolve this issue. 
OdeToFood -> OdeToFood.Data -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.4) 
OdeToFood -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0). OdeToFood   D:\Visual Studio Projects\OdeToFood\OdeToFood\OdeToFood.csproj  1
```

OdeToFOod is the project, OdeToFood.Data is the one of three projects I added EF Core to.

Dear Microsoft, is it asking too much for you to give your error messages in something resembling English? I'm at my wits end with this stupid project. The error message SEEMS to be saying to install 3.1.4 directly to that project. Isn't that what I just did?! Perhaps they mean right-click the project and say manage Nuget for that project instead of "Manage Packages for Solution"? Doesn't make sense to me, but I'll try it. So when I do that it (obviously) already shows 3.1.4 as installed, so that can't be it. So why don't we start nice and fresh, huh? Let's uninstall 3.1.4 from that project and re-install.

Nope. Same error message except this time it mentions a different project, one that never had EF Core installed in the first place. Okay fine Microsoft, I'll play your game. So even though I have no use for it in this second project, I'll install it anyway. Let's see what happens shall we?

OMG.... DISASTER!!!! It's now worse! I still have that error message, but now I have a "package out of dependency constraint" (English please??) and it references ANOTHER package that now has a version conflict, one that hasn't even been touched. What the hell is going on here? I'll bet at this point I can't even go back to Core 2.1.4 anymore. There's got to be some config file or .csproj or something that I can edit because this is unbelievable. I'm trying to follow the directions as best as I can understand them (which isn't much) and it keeps getting worse. And not only that but it appears that EF Core never DID install on this other project anyway so I think there's no fixing this problem at this point, I'm going to have to restore from backup and start over. Why does Microsoft have to make everything so freaking complicated?! Can they at least make this a little more forgiving and user friendly so it doesn't take a PhD to figure out these errors?

[image]

I'm just a beginner at this but how am I supposed to learn this if I can't even get a simple thing like this to compile? I try to follow the directions as best I can and that only makes things worse. I'm ready to declare this project FUBAR, throw my computer through a window, buy a sheep farm and never code again!

Answer (score 0):

We love Scott Allen and his tutorials :)

Seems like scoot have updated entity framework with latest version. Link below

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/OdeToCode/OdeToFood)

If you want to update by yourself i suggest to remove ef Core 2.1 packages from odeToFood & OdeToFood.Data project and install ef core 3.1 in both project accordingly. Hopefully this will resolve the issue. Happy learning.

Comment: Thanks! I think I would rather do this myself, for learning purposes and because I've made customizations. When you say "remove" and "install" you're saying through NuGet? As you can see from my question, I've had little luck doing that.

Comment: I'm stoked that you actually recognized Scott's course from the project name! It's just so confusing the way this is set up with all the configuration files. I like Scott but wish he would explain more detail, just seems he rushes things sometimes but was good with answering questions. It's too bad he's deceased :(

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that (assuming you mean go from 2.1 to 3.1 in Nuget Package Manager" and I got the same error as I pictured above: "Version conflict detected". So I have to ask, version conflict with what? What is it conflicting with? It says install/reference EF Core 3.1.4 directly to project, but that's what I've been doing, right? It seems it's asking me to install to OdeToFood as well, but when I do that I get "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes..." So that makes it worse. ;(